# How does a DHT in a Bittorent client get "bootstrapped"?

Tags: bittorrent, dht

If I have a torrent w/o any trackers in it, and I just started a bittorent client so I have no peers yet...how do I know who to first connect with in the DHT?  It seems like I would have to know at least ONE node in the DHT to get started....

Answer (score 46, accepted):

When a BitTorrent client connects to DHT, there is an initial place that it goes to find peers.  With the original BitTorrent client, there was a url to bitorrent.com that would help get things started.  I tried looking up the reference but I couldn't find it.  Once you've established connections with other clients, then you can do an `announce` on the DHT network to find peers for the torrent you're looking for.

Here's a link to the [BitTorrent specs](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html) that discuss DHT.

> A trackerless torrent dictionary does
>   not have an "announce" key. Instead, a
>   trackerless torrent has a "nodes" key.
>   This key should be set to the K
>   closest nodes in the torrent
>   generating client's routing table.
>   Alternatively, the key could be set to
>   a known good node such as one operated
>   by the person generating the torrent.
>   Please do not automatically add
>   "router.bittorrent.com" to torrent
>   files or automatically add this node
>   to clients routing tables.

Comment: You `announce` on the DHT network? I thought you did a `get_peers()` or even the abstract `get()` to find peers?

Answer (score 54):

The mainline DHT bootstrap nodes are `router.utorrent.com` and a CNAME to it, `router.bittorrent.com`. Port `6881`.

Comment: Thanks! This might be the only place on the web where the full addrs are given in plain text.

Comment: If you look at the DNS those resolve to the same location with router.bittorent.com being a CNAME to router.utorrent.com. They are the same node.

Answer (score 26):

the graph at the bottom of this [DHT monitoring project](http://dsn.tm.uni-karlsruhe.de/english/2936.php) site shows

- dht.transmissionbt.com
- router.utorrent.com
- router.bittorrent.com

as bootstrapping peers

Comment: BitTorrent has published the source code so now you can run your own DHT bootstrap machine: https://github.com/bittorrent/bootstrap-dht

Comment: @stk that link is broken (first miss-configured ssl, then page missing).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor well, this answer is more than _7 years_ old, it happens... anyway, in cases like this, try digging it up at the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20120508202413/https://dsn.tm.uni-karlsruhe.de/english/2936.php

Comment: That is why links are bad. (links are also good, but in this case they can be bad), it can be good to add an image or a quote as well as a link.

Comment: Uhm, no. Links _by themselves_ are bad. You have to put the relevant information in the answer itself, which I clearly did. Those bullets _are the quote_. The link is just a reference to the source.

Answer (score 21):

In BiTTorrent, you have three main options:

- **Torrent File:** some torrent files can embed `nodes` for you to link into the DHT with (in fact, it's recommended when making a torrent file)
- **Hardcoding:** Some torrent clients hard code a few bootstrap nodes (like the ones mentioned by stk). These are usually run by companies and organizations with long-running servers.
- **PEX / Peer Conversations**: You can usually ask for DHT nodes from the people you are downloading other torrents from (if your clients understand eachothers language. ie some versions are incompatible).

Answer (score 13):

`Transmission` uses a [hardcoded bootstrap node](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/browser/trunk/libtransmission/tr-dht.c#L250) for dht if there is no other way to get peers:

```
bootstrap_from_name( "dht.transmissionbt.com", 6881, bootstrap_af(session) );
```

I guess each torrent client uses their own bootstrap node.

Answer (score 8):

For the record, [Deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org/) also uses [hardcoded boostrap nodes](http://git.deluge-torrent.org/deluge/tree/deluge/core/preferencesmanager.py#n271):

```py
dht_bootstraps = set(
    lt_bootstraps.split(',')
    + [
        'router.bittorrent.com:6881',
        'router.utorrent.com:6881',
        'router.bitcomet.com:6881',
        'dht.transmissionbt.com:6881',
        'dht.aelitis.com:6881',
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 4):

A client can learn about other DHT-capable peers through it's interactions with them.  A peer's support for DHT is advertised in it's Handshake.  Once a client discovers at least one good, well-connected DHT peer, it can navigate the DHT to find more and closer DHT peers.  It will remember these peers, called nodes in DHT-speak, between restarts of the software and maintain/update the list continuously while it is running.  In the worse case where a client knows of no good DHT-capable peers, it will require you to download a tracker-based torrent so it can hopefully contact a few good DHT-capable peers it learns about through the tracker.

**Update:**
For it's initial list of DHT peers, as @Seppo points out, a torrent client can use one or more hard-coded DNS names to find the addresses for well-known peers, and it may also include a hard-coded list of peers as a final fallback as well. One limitation of DNS, however, it no port information is provided so a default port of 6881 is generally assumed whereas other means support peers operating on different ports.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the primary nodes I've come across.

```
dht.transmissionbt.com 6881
router.bittorrent.com  6881
router.bitcomet.com    6881
dht.aelitis.com        6881
bootstrap.jami.net     4222
```